How can i wrap an object with a curved surface around another object without distorting its shape?
Greetings. I'm a blender beginner, which means I have no idea what I am doing, so please excuse my probably silly question.
My Goal:
I want to wrap some muscle objects around a face model. However, the muscles were not specifically designed to fit my face model, and I'm struggling to get them to align properly without losing their intended shape.

What i've tried:

Adding a shrink wrap modifier to the muscles:
I tried with different wrap methods but all of them deform the muscles
Adding a lattice Modifier
I followed this tutorial, but the method seems to only work for objects with flat surfaces.
Sculpting the muscles objects to fit the face:
This method is painfully slow, and my results aren’t great (maybe I’m doing it wrong). At this point, I’m not sure if this is my only option.

My Question:
What's the correct way to do this? Maybe something i haven't tried yet, or a different way to do what i've already tried?


Hello could you please show a screenshot of your object, maybe share it?

There’s not going to be a one click way to do this, since Blender has no “intelligent” way of fitting the muscles onto the face.

Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

I would recommend looking into the surface deform modifier

You can make a single surface that matches the form of the object that you want to deform and use that thin surface to deform your object with Surface Deform modifier. This could be some part of your existing model just duplicated and separated into a separate object. The important part is that it needs to be flat. Then you can use Shrink Wrap to deform that surface. Since it's just flat surface, it a can remain flat when shrink-wrapped and your object retains smaller detail and thickness while deformed by that surface.




Or just deform the object manually with proportional editing and/or sculpting. That can be the correct and pretty fast way as well. What you have in the screenshot can easily be done manually in a minute or two. So it might also be worth just practicing a bit more if you want to be able to do that.

Thank you for your response! I tried using the modifiers with the plane as you suggested, but unfortunately, the muscles became very deformed . If sculpting them is a good approach, I’m happy to go that route! However, my only concern is whether sculpting would ruin my existing texture. Would that be an issue?

I think modifiers are a good approach. You can use sculpting or proportional editing to adjust after the modifiers are applied as well as with the modifiers still present before they are applied.  You can adjust the mesh that you made to be deformed by Shrinkwrap. When I talk about sculpting I mainly mean Grab brushes just to move stuff around. I think it's just a matter of learning to do it well. I would recommend experimenting and practicing more.
